# Search a word in a folder that contains multiple .txt file ahk

Tags: search, text, autohotkey

I want to be able to read a lot of text file which i can instantly search all its contents and giving me values of every "NAME"
the text file contains info with different stringnames inside
i wanted to add them every time it has duplicate strings inside which is the NAME

ex.
the output should be like this
DAR050RN  10
DAR012RW  4
DAR016RN  5
DAR027RN  99

```
^F8::
File := "*.txt"             
FileHit := "" 

ArrayName:= []
ArrayName[1]:= "DAR050RN"
ArrayName[2]:= "DAR012RW"
ArrayName[3]:= "DAR016RN"
ArrayName[4]:= "DAR027RN"

ArrayValue:=[] / i dont know if i can put values here

if ErrorLevel
{
    MsgBox, Query canceled.
    Exit
}

Directory := RegExReplace(Directory, "\\$")

If Directory
{
    If(!InStr(FileExist(Directory), "D"))
    {
        msgbox Invalid directory
        Exit
    }
    StringRight, DirectoryEndingChar, Directory, 1
    If(DirectoryEndingChar != "\")
        Directory .= "\"
}

Loop, %Directory%%File%, , 1
{
   FileRead, FileCheck, %A_LoopFileLongPath%
   IfInString, FileCheck, %StringCheck%
      FileHit%A_Index% := A_LoopFileLongPath
}

Loop,%Directory%%File%, *.txt, FR
{

for key, val in ArrayName

    Loop, Read, %A_LoopFileFullPath%, objects.txt
    {

        IfInString, A_LoopReadLine, % val
        {
            StringReplace, CurrentLine, A_LoopReadLine, Name(wstring:64)=
            FileAppend, %CurrentLine%`n

        }
    }
}
return
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Please post any code you may have tried. If you haven't tried anything, just right off the top of my head I'm thinking it would involve using `FileRead` and `RegExMatch` in a loop. Searching these terms in the help file will explain how to use these. https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/AutoHotkey.htm

Comment: I have searched alot but I'm lost and need a lead.

FileSelectFile, files, M3
if (files = "")
{
    MsgBox, The user pressed cancel.
    return
}
Loop, parse, files, `n
{
    if (A_Index = 1)
        MsgBox,
    else
    {
        MsgBox, 4, , The next file is %A_LoopField%.  Continue?
       (read text file string here if true "name and counter++" 
        IfMsgBox, No, break
(print all text "ABC123 (count)" "ABC124 (count) . . ." or save a text.file with all output there)
    }
}
return

Comment: Would you mind puting the code from your comment in your post? It's very hard to understand from comments since there aren't the formatting tools available that posts have.

Comment: I added the code what i have made